# Why can't I shut down Ubuntu on most attempts?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, crash

I do not know why my new Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit cannot be shut down or restart. I have to press and hold the power button to turn off.

I did some googling but I didn't find anything to help. Here is a list of files in `/var/crash`:

```
ali@persian:~$ ls /var/crash/ -l
total 45752
-rw-r----- 1 ali      whoopsie 23795861 Jul 17 11:56 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ali      whoopsie        0 Jul 17 11:56 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 21 19:33 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.uploaded
-rw-r----- 1 ali      whoopsie 17373280 Jul 15 22:24 _usr_lib_mysql-workbench_mysql-workbench-bin.1000.crash
-rw-r----- 1 root     whoopsie  5673893 Jul 17 09:35 _usr_sbin_apache2.0.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     whoopsie        0 Jul 17 09:35 _usr_sbin_apache2.0.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Jul 17 09:36 _usr_sbin_apache2.0.uploaded
```

--edit

after update && upgrade, the problem is retain and did not solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used `sudo shutdown -rF`.

Its about 3 days that I have no problem with shutdown or restart.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen after suspend? If yes, in terminal run

```
$ ps aux | grep suspend
```

If you see a hanging suspend job, it is preventing shutdown.Kill it with

```
$ sudo kill -9 NNNN
```

(Fill in job number from ps output)

This never happened to me till 16.04, now happens often!

Comment: no not after suspend, after while restarting or shutting down